# How to map a new CRUD action in 'routes.rb'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, view, routes

In my 'routes.rb' file I have this code:

```
resources :users
```

that maps my user's controller like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

If I want to map the "reset" view/url for users (**Path**: /users/reset) what code I have to insert in the 'routes.rb' file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options - I'm assuming you're just going to act on the session user so you don't need to pass in an id to operate on? If so, you'll need to make a few additional changes...

Use an explicit route:

```
match "/users/reset" => 'users#reset', :as => 'reset_user'
```

The 'as' part is optional.

Add a new route that operations on a 'collection'. This gets you your route but feels like a hack, I wouldn't recommend it.

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'reset'
  end
end
```

Comment: The second is what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
resources :user do
  member do
    get 'reset'
  end
end
```

See [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) in the Rails Guide you referred to.

Comment: I tried that, but I get this error: "Couldn't find User with ID=reset" because your code will get '/users/:id/reset'. I would like to use a "general" path '/users/reset' the same way as new '/users/new'.

Comment: use `collection` instead of `member`